# Как последовательно переключить active?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Обычный пример, но поставил в тупик, как при клике на "назад" - "вперед" переключать активный класс, буду рад если покажите реализацию на чистом JS, хотя на jQuery тоже не обижусь. Всем спасибо за ответы.

```css
.Example span {
  color: blue;
}

.Example span.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Example">
  <span class="active">1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <span class="prev">назад</span>
  <span class="next">вперед</span>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Нужна как бесконечная карусель, или когда первый `span` `active`, то на `prev` нельзя нажать?

Comment: Бесконечная карусель

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. При клике на "назад"/"вперед" берется индекс элемента (index) с классом `active`
2. Убираем у всех элементов класс `active`, чтоб не продублировался случайно
3. - Если нажат "вперед" и индекс равен количеству элементов, то значит активным делаем активным первый
   - Если нажат "назад" и индекс равен первому, то значит активным делаем активным последний
   - Во всех иных случаях делаем активным элемент `index + 1` или `index - 1` в зависимости от нажатой кнопки `next` или `prev` соответственно

Comment: Алгоритм в принципе понятен, но как давать класс первому или последнему элементу ? Через nth-child как-то не так мне кажется это :)

"во всех иных случаях index + 1"  я это всё в переменную закину, но опять же, как написать, чтоб если там стояла цифра 2 - то он нашел второй элемент и дал ему активный класс ?

Comment: `Через nth-child` - есть **[eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** например.......`чтоб если там стояла цифра 2` - где **там**? ...................`он нашел второй элемент и дал ему активный класс` - есть всё тот же **[eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)**

Comment: А не могли бы вы пример на jquery показать ? Не могу применить js :( Пишу уже часа 2, просто не работает без ошибок и понять не могу в чем проблема. Пробовал скопировать ваш код и применить к себе, gulp рушится, ошибка в js

Comment: @YourDeveloper так может вопрос на ruSO по gulp задать? ;-)  может он  ругается на `let` от ES6

Comment: Я не знаю что это такое, да вроде нет, менял на var всё равно ругается негодяй.

Comment: Вы бы мне подсказали как последнюю часть с циклом переписать на jQuery, а всё что выше я переписал на jQuery и это работает.

Comment: @YourDeveloper с jquery цикл не нужен. Ибо у него есть removeClass (можно применить сразу ко всей коллекции) и addClass (можно 
 применить к индексу с помощью `eq`)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x8a8nfau/1/ - что не так?

Comment: @YourDeveloper всё просто. В моем примере использовалась внутренняя функция, так сказать замыкание, в котором `index` был объявлен во внешней области, **до** функции переключения `go`. А у тебя каждый раз при клике индекс равен 0......... https://jsfiddle.net/awnn4rx1/1/  ........... убираем циклы еще: https://jsfiddle.net/o6cugt45/2/

Comment: Спасибо за терпение и за удочку !

Answer (score 4):

@Алексей Шиманский написал алгоритм, пока я его кодил :D

```js
$(".prev, .next").click(function(){   
    $a = $(".Example span.active");
    
    $x = $(this).hasClass('prev') ? $a.prev() : $a.next(); 
    
    if($x.length > 0){      
      $x.add($a).toggleClass('active');      
    }
    
});
```

```css
.Example span {
  color: blue;
}

.Example span.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Example">
  <span class="active">1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <span class="prev">назад</span>
  <span class="next">вперед</span>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Просто хотел дать удочку вместо рыбы)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это у меня удочка на jquery, у тебя лопата для червей скорее :D

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, объясните пожалуйста вот эти строки:
 
$x = $(this).hasClass('prev') ? $a.prev() : $a.next(); - здесь вроде понятно, если при клике есть класс prev, то листаем назад, иначе вперед

if($x.length > 0){  - вот эта проверка как считает ?? 

И как мне поправить, чтоб когда доходило до конца, при еще одном клике, опять заново начиналось ?

Comment: @YourDeveloper какие вот эти?

Comment: @teran, будь другом, добавь ответ на чистом JS, делаю такое же не могу разобраться с индексами...  Не писать же дубликат вопроса?

Comment: `prev()` и `next()` возвращают пустой jquery-объект (не null), если это первый или последний элемент.  Поэтому следует проверить, что его длина > 0 (т.е. число объектов возращенных селектором)

Comment: @teran, смутно вроде понял, но как подправить, чтоб не останавливалось на 3ке или на 1ке, а дальше переключалось ?

Comment: @Air добавил примерную реализацию в ответ. можно будет под себя всевозможными путями пилить

Answer (score 4):

Рыбка на *JS* :)

```js
function switchImage() {  
    let index = 0;
    
    let prevButton = document.getElementsByClassName('prev')[0];
    let nextButton = document.getElementsByClassName('next')[0];
    prevButton.addEventListener('click', function() { go(this); }, false);
    nextButton.addEventListener('click', function() { go(this); }, false);
    
    function go(el) {
        let images = document.querySelectorAll("#example span");         

        if (el.dataset.type == 'next') {
            index++;
            index = (index > images.length - 1) ? 0 : index;
        }

        if (el.dataset.type == 'prev') {
            index--;
            index = (index < 0) ? images.length - 1 : index;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            images[i].classList.remove("active");

            if (i == index)
              images[i].className += " active";
        }        
    }    
}


switchImage();
```

```css
#example span {
  color: blue;
}

#example span.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <span class="active">1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <span class="prev" data-type="prev">назад</span>
  <span class="next" data-type="next">вперед</span>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Алексей, благодарю...

Comment: Алексей, еще одна просьба, посмотри мой последний вопрос, может ответишь? Не соображу с решением